# Python store JSON values in list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, rest, python-requests

I am trying to create a API query results in json and store the value to a list.

```
import requests
url = "https://api_url/json/"
headers = {
    'auth': "0dXKLHO",
    }
response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers, verify=False)
json_data = response.json()
details = []
for data in json_data["data"]["segment"]:
    output = (data['value'])
    details.append(output)
    print(details)
```

Actual JSON is,

```
{
    "data": {
        "segments": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "event_id": "1",
                "object_id": "0",
                "object_relation": null
                "value": "103"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "event_id": "1",
                "object_id": "0",
                "object_relation": null
                "value": "104"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "event_id": "1",
                "object_id": "0",
                "object_relation": null
                "value": "105"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My code give me the following output,

```
['103']
['103','104']
['103','104','105']
```

But the expected output is in single list,

```
['103','104','105']
```

Comment: You print `details` inside for loop , put it out and you have desired output.

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ oh!. Perfect. got the expected output. Thanks.